# Call to undefined function App\select()

Tags: php, laravel

I have in my model this function and i get the error in my log.

What could be causing this  or do i have import a lib?

PS: Laravel Beginner

> Call to undefined function App\select()

**Model**

```
public function daily_toast() 
{    
    return $this->daily—>select(‘toast’, DB::raw('count(*) as daily_toast'))->get();  
}
```

Comment: `—>select` That's not a `-`, it's a `—`. And `‘toast’` look like the wrong `'`

Comment: can you show class construct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think daily() is relation, try this:

```
  public function daily_toast() 
  {    
     return $this->daily()->select(‘toast’, DB::raw('count(*) as daily_toast'))->get();  
  }
```

Comment: i get an error when i put the parenthesis for the `daily()` saying `unexpected T_STRING`